# Updating data on an index of a array javascript and react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my Todo App i have sucessfully implemented the add and delete functions but the update function is having trouble. What i need it to do is when i click the touchable opacity of a Todo, it should appear in my inputbox and if any change is made then that todo should be updated e.g clicking on abcd must make it appear in input box and changes made to it should be updated. Picture is also added below
[image]

```
export default function Todo() {
  const [getText, setText] = useState('');
  const [getList, setList] = useState([]);

  const addItem = () => {
       setList([...getList, {key: Math.random().toString(), data: getText}]);
       setText('');
    }

  const removeItem = (itemKey) => {  
    setList(() => getList.filter(item => item.key != itemKey));
  }

  const updateFieldChanged = (index) => e => {
    let newArr = [...getList]; // copying the old datas array
    newArr[index] = e.target.value; // replace e.target.value with whatever you want to change it to
    setList(newArr);
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>todo</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Enter Item"
          onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
          value={getText}
        />
        <CustomButton     
          text = 'add'
          color='red'
          title= 'add'
          textSize={20}
          textColor="white"
          onPressEvent={addItem}

        />
      </View>

      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview}>
        {getList.map((item, id) =>
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={item.key}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress= {() => updateFieldChanged(id)}


          >
            <View style={styles.scrollviewItem}>
              <Text style={styles.scrollviewText}>{id}) {item.data}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => removeItem(item.key)}
              >
                <View style={styles.crosstextcontainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.crosstext}>X</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: From where you updating your value where you are getting event e from it can be done only on TextInput

Comment: Your function will never be called here as you need to pass two arguments in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  <TouchableOpacity
            key={item.key}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress= {() => updateFieldChanged(id)}
          >
```

to

```
  <TouchableOpacity
              key={item.key}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              onPress= {() => updateFieldChanged(id,getText)}
            >
```

Here iam passing the text that you need to enter to update a particular field

change your `updateFieldChanged` like this:

```
  const updateFieldChanged = (index, text) => {
      let newArr = [...getList]; // copying the old datas array
      newArr[index].data = text; // replace e.target.value with whatever you want to change it to
      setList(newArr);
      setText('');
  }
```

Here iam assigning the text you entered in the TextInput to the data object, which will update the array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/p0eRVGwOK  here is my snack link if u could take a look

Comment: It's because of the odd behaviour of TouchableOpacity, just add this line to your scroll view keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'} check this https://snack.expo.io/lSeCtL1Rx